# How to bring a dynamically generated HTML table into a JS array?

Tags: php, javascript, html, dom

I'm generating a 2-column HTML table from a php array as follows:

```
<table>
  <?php
    $i=0
    foreach ($fullNameArray as $namePair){
      echo
        "<tr>
          <td id='first ".$i."'>".$namePair[0]."</td>
          <td id='last".$i."'>".$namePair[1]."</td>
        </tr>";
      $i++;
    }
  ?>
</table>
```

What is the best way to explore this table in Javascript, for example to build an array that would replicate the PHP array, i.e., an array of [first name, last name] pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the old-fashioned pure-JavaScript way, you could do some simple DOM traversal.

If you add an `id` to the table, your life will be much easier, especially if you have (or may later add) other tables in the page.

```
<table id="nameTable">
    ...
</table>
```

Now you can access the table in JavaScript and store a reference to it in a variable. You will also want to initialize an empty array/list variable to hold the names later.

```
var nameTable = document.getElementById("nameTable");
var nameArray = [];
```

Next, you begin looping through the child elements of the table, each of which will be a `tr` (table row) element.

```
for (var i=0; i<nameTable.childNodes.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Inside that `for` loop you will build your list of [first name, last name] pairs. You will do this by grabbing the value of each of the two `td` (table data cell) children of the current row.

```
    var dataCells = nameTable.childNodes[i].childNodes;
    var namePair = [dataCells[0].innerHTML, dataCells[1].innerHTML];
```

That should give you a JSON array something like this (my values added):

```
[
    ["Andy", "Jackson"],
    ["Barry", "Obama"],
    ["Benny", "Franklin"],
    ["Georgey", "Washington"],
    ["Billy", "Clinton"]
]
```

To review, the full code would look something like this:

```
var nameTable = document.getElementById("nameTable");
var nameArray = [];

for (var i=0; i<nameTable.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var dataCells = nameTable.childNodes[i].childNodes;
    var namePair = [dataCells[0].innerHTML, dataCells[1].innerHTML];
}
```

**NOTE:** This is fun, but it is likely that the better solution, if you don't mind a hard-coded JSON array in your source code (if you've got the table there anyway it really doesn't matter), is probably to print a `json_encode`d array in a `<script>` tag straight from the PHP, like @JayBhatt suggested. It is likely the faster method, and it puts much less stress on the user's browser.

Comment: Thanks, I think that answers my question.  I need to get better at exploring the DOM...

Comment: I'm getting a `type error - nameTable is null`.  I tried putting the code inside a `window.onload` to make sure I wasn't trying to get the reference before it was loaded, but that makes no difference...

Comment: Did you add `id="nameTable"` to your `<table>` tag? Also, in your `getElementById` call, is it in quotes?

Comment: Sorry, I should have noted that this code is untested. Hence the phrases like "something like this"

Comment: Quick follow up question: what is the advantage (if any) of using the DOM rather than simply using the id of each `<td>` and getting the value this way?

Comment: For one thing, if you have a dynamically generated table, you shouldn't be using IDs on every TD, since each ID should only be used once and it would be a real pain trying to keep track of all the IDs. If you use Classes instead, which you could do, you would likely end up with as much or more code as you have up here, since you would need to manually list each class and loop through each TD with that class, trying to get them in the right place in the JSON structure. Doing it via the DOM will use significantly less code, be more readable and maintainable, and give you far fewer headaches.

Comment: Just the prospect of enumerating every single ID you use should be enough to turn you off from that method. This method also allows you to add as many names as you like to the table without anything breaking. But again, if I didn't get this across strongly enough in my answer, **if possible, you should be printing the JSON string via PHP, not scraping it from the table via JavaScript**. Unless you have a very specific reason not to do that.

Comment: @ KenB - thanks.  The content of the html table will be modified by the user, so I can't use the php array, I need to scrape the table.

Comment: @JDelage In that case, you definitely have a good, specific reason.

Answer (score 1):

Encode your array to Json using PHP's json_encode, assign this string to a javascript variable and decode json to array using javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be assign the json to a hidden input instead a javascript and later get the input value in your javascript Code.